# Parsing incoming Slack attachments with Hubot

Tags: slack, hubot

I'm writing a Slackbot and I want to parse incoming attachments.
From what I understand, I can't use the standard robot.hear, I need to use something called SlackRawListener, but I can't quite understand how I use it :(

Can someone show me an example please?

Comment: Can you post your best attempt at using it, including code you have written and the output you get as well as the output you're hoping for?

Comment: I'm using a standard hubot, and when I use robot.hear I can see the text of the message but not any attachments.

`module.exports = (robot) ->

  robot.hear /.*/i, (msg) ->

     console.log msg`